# Postgres generate_series joined onto result set to fill empty dates within a range

Tags: postgresql

I have a result set that sometimes has missing dates (because no data is present within that week), and need to fill those with zero's. For simplicity I've reduced the query and table down to

```
Table: generated_data
id | data | date_key 
1  |  3   | 2021-12-13 03:00:00.000
2  |  1   | 2021-12-22 05:00:00.000
3  |  4   | 2021-12-24 07:00:00.000
4  |  7   | 2022-01-03 01:00:00.000
5  |  2   | 2022-01-05 02:00:00.000

Query:
Select 
  sum(data) / count(data), 
  DATE_TRUNC('week', date_key AT TIME ZONE 'America/New_York') as date_key
from generated_data
group by DATE_TRUNC('week', date_key AT TIME ZONE 'America/New_York') as date_key 

would produce the following result set: 
3   | 2021-12-13 00:00:00.000
2.5 | 2021-12-20 00:00:00.000
5.5 | 2022-01-03 00:00:00.000
```

but as you can see there's a missing date of 12/27 which I'd like to return in the result set as a zero. I've looked into using generate_series and joining onto the above simplified query, but haven't found a good solution.

The idea would be doing something like

```
SELECT GENERATE_SERIES('2021-11-08T00:00:00+00:00'::date, '2022-01-17T04:59:59.999000+00:00'::date, '1 week'::interval) as date_key
```

but I'm not sure how to join that back to the result query where just the missing dates are added. What would a on clause look like for something like that?

```
final result set would look like 
3   | 2021-12-13 00:00:00.000
2.5 | 2021-12-20 00:00:00.000
0   | 2021-12-27 00:00:00.000
5.5 | 2022-01-03 00:00:00.000
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At first, you should find the min and max of date and generate based on that. Then join a table with generated data

[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=e41968149d768f83a785a09ac1a5565f)

```sql
WITH data_range AS (
  SELECT
    min(date_key) AT TIME ZONE 'America/New_York' min,
    max(date_key) AT TIME ZONE 'America/New_York' max
  from generated_data
),
generated_range AS (
  SELECT DATE_TRUNC(
    'week',
    GENERATE_SERIES(min, max, '1 week'::interval)
  ) AS date FROM data_range
)
SELECT
  coalesce(sum(data) / count(data), 0), 
  DATE_TRUNC('week', gr.date)
FROM 
  generated_range gr
  LEFT JOIN generated_data gd ON 
    DATE_TRUNC('week', gd.date_key AT TIME ZONE 'America/New_York') = gr.date
GROUP BY DATE_TRUNC('week', gr.date)
ORDER BY 2
```

Comment: What could I do if I need to filter on additional joins that happen? That would subsequently filter out the generated_range rows. For example, lets say generated_data joins onto a company table and I want to filter that table down to just a specific company. That would also filter out generated_range. Thoughts on a solution to that?

Comment: If I realize your question, After joining with company table you should use conditions to filter specific row. Like: `INNER JOIN company c ON c.id = gd.company_id AND c.name = 'company-name'`